# Name definition error when defining variables in function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, variables, scope

I have a bit of code that accepts a .csv with a list of filenames as an input, then breaks the filename down into its component parts and re-orders them along with some additional characters.

Input Example:

```
3006419_3006420_ENG_FRONT.jpg
```

Output Example:

```
;E3006419_3006420_FRONT_Image_Container;
```

However, I'd like to make the portion of the for loop that splits up the filename into a function that I can call elsewhere, so that I can re-use it in a second for loop that outputs in a different format. When I try to define a function, though, it seems I have a scoping error with my variables and can't use them in my output.write statement.

**Working Code**

```
from csv import reader
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('USAGE ERROR:\nRun like "python <script.py> <input file.csv>"') #error message if code is not run with correct number of arguments
    exit()

file = open(sys.argv[1]) #open input file
output = open('output.impex','w+') #define output impex file

for line in file:
    nameAndExtension = line.split('.') #split file into filename and file extension
    name = nameAndExtension[0] 
    extension = nameAndExtension[1].replace('\n','') #save file extension as variable extension and remove \n
    elements = name.split('_') #split filename into constituent elements. Filenames are formatted as PARENTSKU_CHILDSKU_LANG_ANGLE.extension, eg '3006419_3006420_ENG_FRONT.jpg'
    parentSKU = elements[0]
    childSKU = elements[1]
    lang = elements[2]
    angle = elements[3]

    output.write(";E" + parentSKU + "_" + childSKU + "_" + angle + '_Image_Container;\n')
```

**Non-Working Code:**

```
from csv import reader
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('USAGE ERROR:\nRun like "python <script.py> <input file.csv>"') #error message if code is not run with correct number of arguments
    exit()

file = open(sys.argv[1]) #open input file
output = open('output.impex','w+') #define output impex file

def lineSplitting(x):
    nameAndExtension = x.split('.') #split file into filename and file extension
    name = nameAndExtension[0] 
    extension = nameAndExtension[1].replace('\n','') #save file extension as variable extension and remove \n
    elements = name.split('_') #split filename into constituent elements. Filenames are formatted as PARENTSKU_CHILDSKU_LANG_ANGLE.extension, eg '3006419_3006420_ENG_FRONT.jpg'
    parentSKU = elements[0]
    childSKU = elements[1]
    lang = elements[2]
    angle = elements[3]

for line in file:
    lineSplitting(line)
    output.write(";E" + parentSKU + "_" + childSKU + "_" + angle + '_Image_Container;\n')
```

I get "NameError: name 'parentSKU' is not defined" I *think* because the of the variable scope - but I don't know what I need to do to make the variable re-usable in the for-loop. What do I need to do to make all that splitting and variable definition into a function?

Comment: you are not returning anything fro the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return your value from the function

```
def lineSplitting(x):
    nameAndExtension = x.split('.') #split file into filename and file extension
    name = nameAndExtension[0] 
    extension = nameAndExtension[1].replace('\n','') #save file extension as variable extension and remove \n
    elements = name.split('_') #split filename into constituent elements. Filenames are formatted as PARENTSKU_CHILDSKU_LANG_ANGLE.extension, eg '3006419_3006420_ENG_FRONT.jpg'
    parentSKU = elements[0]
    childSKU = elements[1]
    lang = elements[2]
    angle = elements[3]

    return parentSKU,childSKU,angle
```

and the next code will call the function

```
for line in file:
    parentSKU,childSKU,angle =lineSplitting(line)
    output.write(";E" + parentSKU + "_" + childSKU + "_" + angle + '_Image_Container;\n')
```

Comment: I see! What is that second part called - where you set the variables equal to the output of the function?

Comment: That works! Is there a name for setting the variables equal to the output of the function?

Comment: you have to return the values from the function which you will use outside the functions,all these are local variables inside the function.